# Creating new sheet based on email address

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro which filters based on email address in column D. It filters email addresses one by one and copies all visible cells into a new sheet. It continues to next email address, until the end.

It is ignoring/not reading some email addresses. It creates a new sheet but doesn't name it based on the email address. It names it as "sheeet22" and leave it empty.

I color each newly created sheet by blue color.

```vb
Dim r As Double
Dim email As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object
Dim lastrow As Double
Dim i As Double
Dim S_UserName As String
Dim sImgFront As String
Dim POV As String
Dim POF As String
Dim Vcost As Double
Dim Fcost As Double

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoiceTracker").Select
Range("D2:D1000000").ClearFormats
Range("D2:D1000000").ClearHyperlinks
Range("D2:D1000000").ClearNotes
Set sh = ActiveSheet
sh.Range("A1:AE1").AutoFilter
r = 1

Do
    r = r + 1
    email = sh.Range("D" & r).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets(email) Is Nothing Then
        sh.Range("A1:AE1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=email
        sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Debug.Print email
        Sheets.Add.Name = email
        Sheets(email).Paste
        ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        sh.ShowAllData
    End If
Loop While sh.Range("D" & r + 1).Value <> ""
```

I tried:

- `Debug.Print` - a value of that email address is there.
- I rewrote that email address to a different email address, and the different email address worked.
- I deleted the first three letters of that email address and it worked.

Comment: I would start by removing the `On Error Resume Next` and see what other errors you are ignoring.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `Sheets` is not just a shortcut for `Worksheets`

Comment: There are limits on what you can use as a tab name in excel - have you looked at those?

Comment: make sure there are not duplicate email addresses/sheet names as you cant have sheets with duplicate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a check for lenght and characters. The max is 31 characters and some characters are illegal

Below is a code used before.

```
Public Function IsValidSheetName(strSheetName As String) As Boolean

   Dim varSheetNameIllegalCharacters As Variant: varSheetNameIllegalCharacters = SheetNameIllegalCharacters

   Dim i As Integer


   For i = LBound(varSheetNameIllegalCharacters) To UBound(varSheetNameIllegalCharacters)
    If InStr(strSheetName, (varSheetNameIllegalCharacters(i))) > 0 Then Exit Function
   Next i

  If len(strSheetName) >= 31 then exit function

  IsValidSheetName = False


  End Function
```

This as function for the Characters

```
Private Function SheetNameIllegalCharacters() As Variant

SheetNameIllegalCharacters = Array("/", "\", "[", "]", "*", "?", ":")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. the issue was length of sheet's name. The name of sheet was always email address and some emails were longer than 31 characters. So I have created new column (sheet names) and used formula LEFT and limited it to 30 characters.

Comment: Great solve, did something similar with the above code! Upvote would be appreciated :)